# I have this code below it's supposed to send a discord embed after 10 messages in a specific channel but for some reason it doesn't and logs no errors

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")
module.exports = {
  name: "test",
  description: "A test command",
  run: async(client, message, args)=>{
    let count = 0;
    let channelId = message.channel.id;
    client.on("messageCreate", async(newMessage)=>{ // dont use "message" here
      if (newMessage.channel.id === channelId) {
        count = count + 1;
         if (count === 10) {
           let embed = new MessageEmbed()
           .setDescription("Hello")
           .setColor("RANDOM")
           return message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] })
         }
      } else if (newMessage.channel.id !== channelId) {
         return;
      }
    })
  }
}
```

I'm trying to make a command that sends an embed to a specific channel every 10 messages are sent but the above code isn't working and I'm not getting any errors either could someone help?

Comment: Which version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: Where doy call this `run` method? Inside another `client.on("messageCreate", ()=>{})`?

Comment: You shouldn't be nesting messageCreate events, define the `count` variable in a global scope and *only* increment in the event